# Custom controller for TextFormField clears text entered when focus removed - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a custom controller for TextFormField, but I use it in my widgets it clears the input upon releasing focus from the input. the same setup works fine with the local widget set up with the same but I want to have a common widget to use throughout the application for better code maintainability. How can have the input intact entered into the input field??

Custom Input Widget-

```
import 'package:HSSE/screens/constant.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppInput extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppInput(
      {Key key,
      this.correct = false,
      this.hintText,
      this.inputLabel,
      this.labelFont = 18.0,
      this.labelFontWeight,
      this.validators,
      this.keyboard,
      this.length,
      this.icon,
      this.trailingIcon,
      this.readOnly = false,
      this.inputController,
      this.onTap = null,
      this.onInputValueChange,
      this.labelText})
      : super(key: key);

  final bool correct;
  final String hintText;
  final String labelText;
  final String inputLabel;
  final double labelFont;
  final FontWeight labelFontWeight;
  final Function validators;
  final Function onInputValueChange;
  final TextInputType keyboard;
  final int length;
  final Icon icon;
  final Icon trailingIcon;
  final bool readOnly;
  final Function onTap;
  final TextEditingController inputController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Color(0Xffcacaca), width: 0.75),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            labelText,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: labelFont),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            readOnly: readOnly,
            keyboardType: keyboard,
            maxLength: length,
            controller: inputController,
            cursorColor: apmt_color,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: icon,
              suffixIcon: trailingIcon,
              errorStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: hintText,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              fillColor: Colors.red,
            ),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            onChanged: (value) {
              onInputValueChange(value);
            },
            validator: (value) {
              return validators(value);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I use it into my other widget like below -

```
final TextEditingController emailCtrl = TextEditingController();
AppInput(
   inputController: emailCtrl,
   keyboard: TextInputType.emailAddress,
   hintText: Localizer.of(context).translate('inspectorNameHint'),
   labelText: Localizer.of(context).translate('inspectorName'),
   validators: (String name) {
   if (name.isEmpty)
     return Localizer.of(context)
            .translate('inspectorNameError');
     },
   )
```

the input gets clears when the focus gets removed from the input field it works fine with the same setup on the local widget but I want to make a common widget to optimize the code.

Comment: Are you using a stateful widget in the parent widget ? if not the TextEditingController may be rebuilding itself and that is creating a new controller everytime

Comment: @ValdaXD yes i am using stateful widgets but there is no setState anywhere but i guess keypad reloads the widgets

Comment: Can you please share all the code where you are using AppInput ?@SatishRaizada